# Not Picking Up Image If False

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my codeigniter form, I am trying to set an `else if` for my data image. Currently it picks up `if` when image exists. But need it to pick up my *no_image.png*, if no image exist using the same code below.

```
<?php
class Users extends MX_Controller {

public function index() {

  $this->getForm();

}

protected function getForm($user_id = 0) {

$this->load->model('admin/user/users_model');

$user_info = $this->users_model->getUser($user_id);

if (trim($this->input->post('image'))) {

  $data['image'] = $this->input->post('image');

} elseif (!empty($user_info)) {

  // This Location Image Works Fine.

  $data['image'] = config_item('base_url') . 'image/catalog/' . $user_info['image'];

} else {

  // Should Display If No Image Present In Database Does Not Work.

  $data['image'] = config_item('base_url') . 'image/'. 'no_image.png';
}

}

$this->load->view('user/users_form', $data);

}
```

*View Page :*

```
<div class="form-group">
<label  for="input-image" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><?php echo $entry_image; ?></label>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
<a href="" id="thumb-image" data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail">
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you never get `no_image` even when there isn't an image, it's because `!empty($user_info))` is always `true` because `$user_info` is never `0, null, false, array, "", ''`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Do you have a code example to what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in image folder the no_image.png exists. And it is accessible directly.Like
, you can try directly open the link in your browser as http://www.yoursiteurl/image/no_image.png.

If it opens then there is two possibilities

1. in your config file there is no end slash for baseurl.
2. The code never executes the else block

If the dierct link does not open then  a htaccess problem may exists.

Hope this will help you.

Or your elseif condition may be like this

```
            elseif(!empty($user_info) && $user_info['image'] && file_exists(config_item('base_url') . 'image/catalog/' . $user_info['image'])){
            ...
            }
            // + so your user info is valid but user picture is not available
```

Comment: Does not help nothing to do with that. Image links work. just else if is not working

Comment: I had to create a secondary if statement to make no_image work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a if statement below to make it work for no_image.png now works this way.

```
if (trim($this->input->post('image'))) {
$data['image'] = $this->input->post('image');
} elseif (!empty($user_info)) {
$data['image'] = config_item('base_url') . 'image/catalog/' . $user_info['image'];
} else {
$data['image'] = '';
}

if ($user_info['image'] == FALSE) {
$data['image'] = config_item('base_url') . 'image/'. 'no_image.png';
}
```